# For loop instead of long if condition in order to reduce computing time

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, microcontroller

I have some code that looks like shown below. I have simplified it to get my point across. It contains an array. In the first part each value of the array minus a certain value shall be compared to a margin value.
If all of the conditions are met the µC should stop run a simple function.
Else the µC should run a calculation with the values of the array. This calculation has a few multiplications that are run for every value.

```
uint32_t value[8];
uint16_t othervalue;

if ((value[0] < othervalue && value[1] < othervalue && value[2] < othervalue && value[3] < othervalue && value[4] < othervalue && value[5] < othervalue && value[6] < othervalue && value[7] < othervalue)
{
    othervalue = 100;
    simplefunction();
}
else
{
    calculatewithallvalues(values);
}
```

I have noticed that i could probably improve the code. The calculations in the "else" only need to be done if the condition for that specific value is not met. Therefore in certain cases the calculation does not have to be done for every value. I came up with a different approach using a for loop. However, this code is longer an maybe more confusing. The extra if loop at the end is needed to account for the possibility that all values meet the condition.

```
uint32_t value[8];
uint16_t othervalue;
uint8_t calc_needed = 0;
int i;
for (i=0; i <7; i++)
{
    if (value[i] < othervalue)
    {
        //do nothing
    }
    else
    {
        calculatewithvalue(values[i]);
        calc_needed = 1;
    }
if (calc_needed == 0)
{
    othervalue = 100;
    simplefunction();
}
```

Which is the better solution or is there a third solution?

Comment: The first solution is bad because the statement extends off the side of the screen.

Comment: Fiddling's silly comment aside :) - your first option is the way to do, IMHO, even if it's a bit tedious to read and write. Make sure you reorder it to have the most likely tests to fail up front in the expression.

Comment: Well, how complex is your `calculatewithvalue()` function? How likely is it that any particular Test will fail, causing `calculatewithallvalues()` to be executed? If each calculation is expensive, and it is likely that one of the conditions will fail (but not all of them), then your second version should be faster.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Optimizing the if condition might not yield a noticeable difference, if the main problem is the calculation itself. The first example will always recalculate everything, no matter if only one of the conditions is met, or all of them. The second approach will only recalculate what's strictly necessary.

Comment: 1) there is a `break;` missing in the second fragment. 2) `calculatewithvalue(values[i]);` is different from `calculatewithvalues(values);`

Comment: @wildplasser looks intentional to me, notice `calculatewithvalue()` (meaning only one of the values) vs. `calculatewithallvalues()`.  I think those two functions being different is the entire point of this.

Comment: The calculatewithallvalues() is basically the calculatewithvalue() run i times.

Comment: @FelixG the calculatewithvalue() contains a few multiplications, if loops and other calculations. But it is run on an 8-bit AVR µC

Comment: @Uncle_Drew So i'm correct in assuming that those calculations are what you're actually trying to avoid? It's been a while since i've last worked with AVR µCs, but IIRC they usually don't have a long pipeline (so branches are relatively inexpensive), which would again point towards your second version being the better one. But the best option when it comes to optimizations is to just try it out: compile both variants and then either measure the difference, or look at the assembler code and just add the cycles together (which you can find somewhere in the documentation of the µC)

Answer (score 0):

There is a third solution:

---

```
for(i=0; i < 7; i++) {
    if (value[i] < othervalue ) continue;
    break;
    }

if (i == 7) { // loop completed; all values were below othervalue
    othervalue = 100;
    simplefunction();
    }
else    {
    calculatewithallvalues(values);
    }
```

Comment: This looks better than my solutions, but it does not limit the calculation to only the values were the condition is not met.

Comment: Your two fragments were not equivalent. I stuck with the first. And: wihout the actual requirements and the function(s), the question cannot be answered.